# Error in hosts.allow due to semicolon in comment

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, centos7, sshd

I am trying to automate entries in hosts.allow(I have a pre-defined set of IPs to be added). My script executes well and writes the following entries in hosts.allow -

```
ALL:A.B.C.D      #AddedByNayasa-06-Aug-2020(00:36:58)
ALL:W.X.Y.Z      #AddedByNayasa-06-Aug-2020(00:36:58)
```

where A,B,C,D,W,X,Y,Z are numbers of public IPs. The text after # is a marker added by the script to let user know that it is not added by a human but rather by a script.
**Problem** occurs due to the semicolon in the timestamp. sshd gives the following error in /var/log/secure -

```
/etc/hosts.allow, line 14: bad option name: "36"
```

I am unable to understand why sshd is not treating the <s>semicolon</s> colon as a part of comment and ignoring it since it is written after a hash. Some clue would be really helpful. Also I am unable to make ssh connection due to this error.

Comment: Where do you see a semicolon? Semicolon is `;`, colon is `:`.

Comment: Comments aren't allowed in the middle of the line, it has to be the whole line.

Comment: My  bad, I meant colon.

Answer (score 1):

From the `hosts.allow(5)` [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/5/hosts.allow):

> Blank lines or lines that **begin** with a '#' character are ignored. This permits you to insert comments and whitespace so that the tables are easier to read.

The line has to begin with `#` to make it a comment, they aren't allowed in the middle of a rule.

So you should change your script to write something like:

```
#AddedByNayasa-06-Aug-2020(00:36:58)
ALL:A.B.C.D  
#AddedByNayasa-06-Aug-2020(00:36:58)    
ALL:W.X.Y.Z
```

or more compactly:

```
#AddedByNayasa-06-Aug-2020(00:36:58)
ALL:A.B.C.D  
ALL:W.X.Y.Z 
#EndAddedByNayasa
```